# iOS - How to get first charater of string from NSMutableArray and store it in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

```
- (void)loadData: (NSMutableArray *)myMutableArray  {

    self.myMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSString *str in myMutableArray) {

        NSString *key = [str substringToIndex:1];

        NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);

        NSLog(@"str: %@", str);

        if ([self.myMutableDict objectForKey:key]) {

            NSMutableArray *list = (NSMutableArray *)[self.myMutableDict objectForKey:key];

            [list addObject:str];

            [self.myMutableDict setObject:list forKey:key];

        } else {

            NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:str, nil];

            [self.myMutableDict setObject:list forKey:key];
        }

    }

    [self.tblAlphabeticalOrder reloadData];

}
```

Comment: I've few strings in NSMutableArray. 
NSLog(@"str: %@", str); is logging all data properly but NSLog(@"Key: %@", key); is logging the first letter of first string only. What is going on i'm getting confuse. Can anyone reply me asap?

Comment: Not understand what you want?

Comment: I would like to take first letter of every string from NSMutableArray and put it in Dictionary key.

Comment: Please provide sample data for what you are trying to do. What are the objects in myMutableArray?

Comment: NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Shyam, Ram, Hari, Gita, Rita, Sita, Aab, Bcc, Zee, Alphabet, Order, Monday, File, Edit, Product, Debug, Source, Control, Window, Help, Navigate, Editor, Find, View, Xcode, Home", nil];
    self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
    
    self.myMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (id str in self.myMutableArray) {
        NSString *key = [str substringToIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
        NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
str shows all data, but key shows only S.

Comment: You are not getting the first letter, you are getting the first UTF-16 code point which is not even a complete Unicode character. Really tell us what you actually want to do.

Comment: @RoshanRijal do edit the question with code in the comment section you wrote

Comment: NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Shyam, Ram, Hari, Gita, Rita, Sita, Editor, Find, View, Xcode, Home", nil];                                                                                                                            
    self.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
    
    self.myMutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (id str in self.myMutableArray) {
        NSString *key = [str substringToIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
key shows only S. but i like to take first letter of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Your mutable array has only one very long string with lots of commas in it.  You need to quote each item separately:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Shyam", @"Ram", @"Hari", @"Gita", .....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm so sorry that I disturbed you.. Shamed on me :)